# How is the following number stored in lua?

Tags: lua, numbers, store, numeric

I have this number :

```
b = 1.324567890123456789
```

and the question was ask how was it stored in lua? Now when I type print(b), it shows that the end digits are

```
...1235
```

Now the question gave me the options of

```
...12345
```

or

```
...12346
```

or the option of none on the list -- and i was just wondering if anyone could help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Lua stores real numbers as double precision floating point values.

`print` calls `tostring`, which converts doubles to strings using `"%.14g"`. [1]

Use `string.format("%.17g",b)` if you want more decimals.

[1] https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html#LUA_NUMBER_FMT

Comment: yea, this ^.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: To the question "_how is the following number stored in Lua?_", it is worth pointing out that Lua uses whatever double precision type the underlying C implementation uses. C does not require IEEE 754 for floating point values, and in fact places few restrictions on how an implementation may represent floating point values.